# Como fazer uma página com blocos full utilizando bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, css3, twitter-bootstrap

Preciso fazer algo conforme a imagem, utilizando bootstrap.

Alguém ja passou por isso? Tem alguma idéia de como fazer?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Existem algumas formas de fazer isso. A que usei, foi criar um contêiner geral com a class `container-fluid` o que faz com que a `div` ocupe todo o espaço da tela. Nas partes que a linha não deve seve ser `full-width` usei um `col-md-10` [por exemplo] com offset de 1.

[No Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/hvVro629323y3PlKi897?p=preview).

Obs1: Usando Bootstrap 4, porém a solução para outras versões é facilmente adaptada.

Obs2: A visualização pode ser aberta no modo responsivo, pode mexer a vontade para ver o comportamento, principalmente com a página 'completa'.

Comment: Entendi, só que dessa forma o conteúdo não respeita o container principal né?

Comment: Se não entendi errado o que você quis dizer, o conteúdo irá respeitar suas respectivas `rows` e `divs`. O `conteiner` é apenas uma "embalagem" para o conteúdo.

Answer (score 0):

Você já usou Materialize? Acho ele melhor para criar esse tipos de blocos...

Porem no Bootstrap você consegue distribuindo as células que deseja dentro do contêiner do tamanho que deseja. Exemplo:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    <div class="col-md-6"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Depois e só estilizar com o CSS.